# CentOS 7 download and install php7.0-cli offline

Tags: centos, php

I need to install php7.0-cli to the cerver which is not connected to the internet. For this purpose I try to download and install php7.0-cli from package from the following source:

```
https://pkgs.org/download/php70-php-cli
```

but when I execute the following command:

```
 sudo rpm -Uvh /opt/lampp/htdocs/php70-php-cli-7.0.21-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm
```

it says:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    php70-php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.21-1.el7.remi is needed by php70-php-cli-7.0.21-1.el7.remi.x86_64
```

so it requires so far:

```
php70-php-common-7.0.21-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm
php70-php-json-7.0.21-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm
php70-runtime-1.0-5.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm
```

which I also download and try to install. The problem is that

```
php70-php-json-7.0.21-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm
```

requires

```
php70-php-common-7.0.21-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm
```

which in turn requires

```
php70-php-json-7.0.21-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm
```

and so forth. So the question is how to install php7.0-cli on CentOS machine which is not connected to the internet? Maybe there are some ready packages which already come with all the stuff needed for php7.0-cli easy offline installation? Do I need to manually download all packages which are required? Maybe there is a whole php package which can be downloaded and installed to the server offline?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the files in a directory and install them at the same time with

```
yum install /path/php*rpm
```

so the dependency resolution can take into account everything you want to install at the same time.

Comment: is it possible to download all libs required by php7.0-cli in order to meet all dependency requirements from another, online CentOS machine?

Comment: Not in a practical way.

Comment: Yes, set "keepcache=1" in yum.conf, run the transaction, and the packages will be downloaded in /var/cache/yum/x86_64/*/*/packages directory

Answer (score 0):

From a Fedora26 machine with latest dnf.

Note: *recursive* option returns 192 packages at time of writing.

```
dnf install 'dnf-command(repoquery)' 'dnf-command(download)'

mkdir -p /tmp/repo/Packages && cd $_

PKGS=$(dnf --quiet \
  --disablerepo='*' \
  --enablerepo=centos \
  --repofrompath centos,http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/ \
  --enablerepo=remi \
  --repofrompath remi,http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/safe/x86_64/ \
  repoquery \
  --requires php70-php-cli \
  --resolve --recursive)

dnf --disablerepo='*' \
  --enablerepo=centos \
  --repofrompath centos,http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/ \
  --enablerepo=remi \
  --repofrompath remi,http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/safe/x86_64/ \
  download \
  $PKGS

dnf clean packages

cd /tmp/repo/

createrepo .
```

Copy the /tmp/repo directory to the CentOS7 machine and add a new local.repo as

```
[local]
baseurl=file:///tmp/repo/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```